# Using Poisson distribution to generate random integers

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution, random-generation

I'm trying to generate random integers which have Poisson distribution. [The open source library GSL has one such distribution](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Poisson-Distribution.html#The-Poisson-Distribution).

> Function: `unsigned int gsl_ran_poisson (const gsl_rng * r, double mu)`
>   This function returns a random integer from the Poisson distribution with mean `mu`. The probability distribution for Poisson variates is `p(k) = {mu^k over k!} exp(-mu)`

I want to know what it actually returns. Does it return `k` for a particular value of `p(k)`?

For a particular value of `mu`,  `k` can take values from `0,1,2,3...`
So if I specify a value for `mu`, do I have an upper bound on the values returned by this function?

Comment: No, there is no upper bound on the Poisson distribution.

Comment: if you want an upper bound, you could truncate it at something large and redraw when it gets over the bound...

Comment: Thanks. And is my understanding that the function returns `k` correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to generate random integers which have Poisson distribution.
>   I want to know what it actually returns. Does it return k for a particular value of p(k)?

No. The part you quoted describes what it does quite clearly. It returns a random $X$ which has $P(X=k)=p(k)$. If you tell it $\mu$ you'll get a set of random counts from a Poisson($\mu$) distribution.

> For a particular value of $\mu$, $k$ can take values from 0,1,2,3...
>   So if I specify a value for $\mu$, do I have an upper bound on the values returned by this function?

No. For any fixed value $M$, there's still some chance of exceeding $M$, though it may be vanishingly small. (Well, because it's implemented on a computer with finite precision, there's always *some* limit - you can't store something bigger than the biggest integer, for example - and the exact behavior as it approaches or goes beyond whatever limit exists depend on implementation.)

Comment: Thanks. When you say it returns `X`, doesn't it mean `k` because `P(X=k)` means probability that `X` takes a value `k`

Comment: $X$ is the random variable while in the pmf, $k$ indexes the values it can take. The random variable is denoted $X$ up to the point you observe it. Once you observe it (or in this case, generate it), it takes some particular value, $x$, say. You should feel free to call that observed value $k$ as long as you don't get confused between the observed value and the dummy over the domain of the variable.

Comment: Thanks again. Another question. Lets say I have a list of `400` uniform random numbers between `1 and 1000`. On this list I want to do `isPresent(x)` where `x` is a variable obtained from Poisson distribution. Now for the `mu` I choose `500`. Is this practical? If I choose a value of `mu` as say `3`, I get numbers close to `3` and on the big list of `400` numbers I would be searching only a handful of numbers. So does my choice of `mu` as `500` make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by practical here. What are the properties you seek/what are the limitations you want/need? Note that making the mean of the Poisson 500, you'll usually only observe a range covering about 120-150 values. The largest value will generally be up around 560-580 and the smallest around 425-445. The number of unique values will be close to but typically a bit less than 100.

Comment: You kind of answered my question. I was looking for a Poisson distribution which would have maximum coverage. If I choose `mu` as `3` then I would get values from `0` to `6`. But my list can have numbers from `1` to `1000`. So I think I can get a maximum coverage if I choose `1000/2` which is `500`. Am I correct?

Comment: No, actually! It depends on what exactly you mean by coverage (max-min? number of unique values present?), but since the standard deviation is the square root of the mean, you'll cover a bigger spread of values if you make it larger than 500. e.g. if you made it 860 say, you'd cover nearly 1/3 more values (while still staying inside the range almost always). If you want to cover a bigger fraction of the values, choose something other than the Poisson; perhaps the negative binomial.

Comment: Yes. By `coverage` I mean maximize `max-min`. I'm not following how  you got `860`. In general for a list containing values in the range `[0,max]` what should I choose as `mu` to get maximum `coverage`

Comment: 860 was just as large as I was prepared to go while keeping the risk of going above 1000 really small. Any value for $\mu$ will carry some risk of an observation above 1000. How much does that matter?

Comment: actually it doesn't matter much. The function `isPresent(x)` will just return `false`. Basically a value above `1000` for `mu=500`, is asking for `P(X=2mu)` right?

Comment: No. P(X>1000) is not P(X=1000). If some values above 1000 won't hurt you, but you want to maximize max-min, you'll want mu somewhere above 900.

Comment: Scratch that; it's somewhere in the mid 890s

Comment: I can use `mu=max/1.1` or `mu=max/1.2`. Which one would you suggest. I tried with range `[0,2^20]` and generated `2^21` Poisson RV with `mu=(2^20/1.1)`. All the `2^21` numbers generated were less than `max=2^20`. And this gave me coverage close to `1%`. Using `mu=max/1.2` gave coverage less than `1%`.

Comment: Just to note that the usual way that Poisson variates are drawn is by repeatedly sampling standard exponentials until the sum exceeds $\mu$.  The number of samples is the variate.  If $\mu$ is very large, rejection sampling is exact and fast using a Gaussian proposal distribution.

Comment: arunmoezhi The standard deviation is NOT proportional to the mean, so you can't simply scale the mean for a different max and expect it to work. If you wanted a different problem solved *you should have asked about that problem*. And if you wanted a rule that worked for a bunch of different max values, you should have said that instead.

Comment: I understand.  I will post another question